# Set seed or random seed using R code.How to do it?

Tags: r

I want to set any number as a seed.This is my R code.Is it correct?It is incorrect please give me a the R code for that.

`set.seed(45)`

Answer (score 0):

That's it. After running this line, the following line with random components will produce the same results every time.

```
set.seed(10)
rnorm(10)

set.seed(10)
rnorm(10)
```